# How to use Incomplete paths in app get (Express js)

Tags: node.js, express

Hay everyone, I wrote a simple express js code that has six different routes:
 `"/`,
`"/routes/show-stocks"`,
`"/routes/show-stocks/btc"`,
`"/routes/show-stocks/eth"`,
`"/routes/show-stocks/ada"`,
`"/routes/show-stocks/doge"`.
I used `app.use` to be able to use `"/show-stocks"` as the path insted the full one: `"/routes/show-stocks`
**this is how I did it: (app.js)**

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Testing on Mac"));

const get_stocks = require("./routes/show-stocks");
app.use("/show-stocks", get_stocks);

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Testing on Mac on port: " + port));
```

So if the user want to reach `/routes/show-stocks/btc` he only need to type `/show-stocks/btc`
**This is my "/routes/show-stocks.js":**

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/btc", (req, res) => {
  // ...
});

router.get("/ada", (req, res) => {
  // ...
});

router.get("/eth", (req, res) => {
  // ...
});

router.get("/doge", (req, res) => {
  // ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

But now I need to use `import` instead of `require` in my `app.js` file. My problem is that I do not know how I can implement this code with "import" instead, and preserve the same logic.
Can anyone help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

notice the `import express from "express";` and `import get_stocks from "./routes/show-stocks.js";`

```js
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Testing on Mac"));

import get_stocks from "./routes/show-stocks.js";
app.use("/show-stocks", get_stocks);

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Testing on Mac on port: " + port));
```

You'll need to add the `"type": "module"` to your package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

My quick improvised route file:
Notice the `export default router` at the bottom.

```js
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/btc", (req, res) => {
  res.send("btc");
});

router.get("/ada", (req, res) => {
  res.send("ada");
});

router.get("/eth", (req, res) => {
  res.send("eth");
});

router.get("/doge", (req, res) => {
  res.send("doge");
});

export default router;
```

Comment: I'm afraid I did not express my question properly, please consider checking out my updated question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: oh I did not read you answer properly. Thank you it is working now

Comment: I've updated my post and tried to clarify some things. I hope it helps :)